# Run a specific unit tests in Python from main()

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to run only a single test from the unit tests provided in a class. So assuming

```
class MytestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_false(self):
        a = False
        self.assertFalse(a, "Its false")

    def test_true(self):
        a = True
        self.assertTrue(a, "Its true")
```

I would like to run only *test_false*. Based on the Q&A provided on this site and online, I used the following lines of code in my main class

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  # Indentation was wrong
    singletest = unittest.TestSuite()
    singletest.addTest(MytestSuite().test_false)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(singletest)
```

I keep getting errors while trying to add the test. Mainly:

> File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 189, in **init** 
> (self.**class**, methodName)) 
> ValueError: no such test method in <class '**main**.MytestSuite'>: runTest

Do I need a specific runTest method in my class? Is there a way to run particular tests that may belong to different suites? For example, **method A** belonging to **suite class 1** and **method B** belonging to **suite class 2**. Surprisingly this has proven to be a difficult thing to find online. There are multiple examples of doing it through the command line, but not from the program itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're just passing the wrong thing to `addTest`. Rather than passing in a bound method, you need to pass a new instance of `TestCase` (in your case, an instance of `MyTestSuite`), constructed with the *name* of the single test you want it to run.

```
singletest.addTest(MyTestSuite('test_false'))
```

---

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) has a great deal of additional information and examples on this.